# threeJS Raycaster.set() not detecting intersections

Tags: three.js

I have a problem with detecting intersections when casting Raycast.set(). When I use Raycast.setFromCamera() method everything works.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
var mesh = 'some mesh';

var raycast = new THREE.Raycaster();
var from = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 300);
var to = new THREE.Vector3(0, -100, 300);
raycast.set(from, to);

var intersection = raycast.IntersectObject(mesh);
if(intersection.lenght < 0) {
   alert('Intersection!');
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? The ray is definitely intersecting the mesh, I'm also using ArrowHelper to make sure, however I always get 0 intersections.

Comment: `IntersectObject` and `lenght` are both spelled wrong. This code shouldn't even run. Are there errors in the Javascript console? It should be `intersectObject` and `length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

```
raycaster.set( origin, direction );
```

and `direction` is a `Vector3` that must be normalized, that is, have length equal to 1.

You can normalize a `Vector3` like so:

```
vector.normalize();
```

three.js r.80

Comment: Thank you !  This helped me 6y later.